# Book about a woman who became the maid of a wealthy werewolf

Tags: story-identification, books, werewolf

This was a werewolf story but it started as the view point of a maid. She became a maid for this wealthy werewolf to avenge her father’s death, but she fell for the werewolf and he introduced her to his clan or society of other werewolves. She ends up pregnant by his brother and together they are exiled from Europe or the UK to the American frontier. I think the book was from the 90’s perhaps. I took off the dust cover and remember the book itself was red.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this?

Comment: https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/199640187-the-alpha-and-the-maid?

Comment: https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/63842141-royal-lycan-court?